# Wierd pixel issues in final render (GPU only)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, artifacts

I recently noticed with the new Blender update to 2.90.0 these dark, vertical, one pixel wide artifacts on my final render. 
[image: Metallic surface with dark, vertical, one pixel wide artifacts] 
It only happens with my AMD GPU:

- Software version `2020.0515.1537.28108`
- Driver version `19.50.29.27-200515a-355311C-RadeonSoftwareAdrenalin2020`
- OpenGL version `26.20.11000.13587`
- Vulkan Driver Version `2.0.137`
- Windows version `10 (64 bit)`

With my Intel (i7) CPU it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest version for the AMD Graphics Card `2020.0909.2058.37766` the pixel isssue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this won't be of much help, instead, this problem has happened to me with my new MSI RX 580 I received today I'm having this exact same problem. I've already tried completely wiping old drivers and replacing with new ones. I've tried going back to blender 2.83 to see if it's a 2.9 bug, for me, it's still not working. Did your GPU work in 2.83 or any other version of blender?

Comment: Yes my GPU did work in any other version without these weird pixel issues.